# Why does airflow return two different lists of DAGs?

Tags: airflow

If I run the command `airflow list_dags` it returns a list of DAGs.  However, that list of DAGs is different than the list of dags I see in the web interface under the DAGs tab.  The `airflow list_dags` command is only returning the tutorial DAGs and not the DAGs in the airflow/dags directory.

Why is airflow giving me two different lists of DAGs?

I'm running Airflow 1.8.1.

Comment: Did you try restarting the Airflow webserver? Or did you change your `AIRFLOW_HOME` variable in one but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

The list of dags returned by **airflow list_dags** should be same as the dags that you see on the web interface. To resolve the difference follow the steps:

1. Set the airflow home path in your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc file:
   **export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow** [You can customize this path]
2. Restart the webserver if it's already running:
   **ctrl+c** and then **airflow webserver -p 8080**

Now both the places should reflect the same list of dags.

Answer (score -1):

After setting the airflow home path, you need to check the tag "dags_folder" in your airflow.cfg, then you need to run airflow webserver -p any port you choose, if you want to make sure if the dags are really running as accepted you should check the log of the scheduler airflow scheduler